# Efficiently Exporting Relationships From Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have a relatively small but growing database (2M nodes, 5M relationships). Relationships often change. I periodically need to export the list of relationships for some other computations.

At present, I use a paginated query, but it gets slow as the value of `skip` increases

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) RETURN ID(a) AS id1, ID(b) AS id2, TYPE(r) AS r_type
SKIP %d LIMIT 1000
```

I am using `py2neo`. The relevant bit of code:

```
while (count <= num_records):
    for record in graph.cypher.stream(cq % (skip, limit)):
        id1 = record["id1"]
        id2 = record["id2"]
        r_type = record["r_type"]
```

Is there a better / more efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to skip / limit in the first place.

Neo can easily output gigabytes of data.

See this blog post for another way of doing that: http://neo4j.com/blog/export-csv-from-neo4j-curl-cypher-jq/

You can also use Save as CSV in Neo4j Browser after you ran a query.

Comment: I have 1TB data in Neo4J and I doubt that it can handle all in one request. Also I'm not sure if I can pipe all these data through "jq". I will give it try but just want to see if there is better solution for large-scale exports.